# Geometry Problem [Solution]

Tags: geometry, proof-verification, euclidean-geometry

> Let $ABC$ be an acute triangle inscribed on the circumference
>   $\Gamma$. Let $D$ and $E$ be points on $\Gamma$ such that $AD$ is
>   perpendicular to $BC$ and $AE$ is diameter. Let $F$ be the
>   intersection between $AE$ and $BC$. Prove that, if $\angle DAC = 2\angle DAB$, then $DE = CF$.

The well-known fact $\angle BAH=\angle CAO$ implies that $\angle DAE=\angle CAE,$ so by Thales and AAS we get $\triangle DAE\cong\triangle CAE$ which implies $DE=CE.$ Then note that
$$\angle EFC=\angle BFA=90-\angle DAF=90-\angle CAF=\angle FEC$$so $\triangle EFC$ is isosceles and therefore $CE=CF.$

I did not understand this solution well, it is missing some more information. And who is H?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$H$ is the orthocenter of $ABC$, and $O$ is the circumcenter of $ABC$.